# Can Convolutional Neural Networks be applied in domains other than image recognition?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

I'm new in this argument, my question is:

Can convolution be applied in other contexts different from image recognition?
Is there a good source to learn from?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Convolutional Neural Networks(CNNs) can and have been applied to non-image problems. Arguably, any problem in which the location of a feature(s) is relevant can be attempted via CNNs. CNNs works under the assumption that points close to each other in the data share some correlations/relationship whist points further apart don't share as much information. So, theoretically, if you can phrase your problem so that it meets this requirement(s), it can be attempted by a convolutional neural network. Here are few applications of CNNss that are dont involve images:

- [Speech recognition](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6857341/?reload=true)
- [Character-level Convolutional Networks for Text Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01626)
- [Text classification using CNNs](https://chara.cs.illinois.edu/sites/sp16-cs591txt/files/0226-presentation.pdf)
- [Natural Language Processing](http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/)
- [Time Series Forecasting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04691.pdf)
- [Sentence modeling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2188)
- I've used 1-D CNNs on spectral data. Here are some examples of [CNNs applied to spectral data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01927) :

  - [Spectral Convolutional Neural Network for music classification](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2af4/f72c2326c15616ad9f5cf18d5278d6608a14.pdf)
  - [Convolutional neural network based classification for hyperspectral data](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7730323/)

Answer (score 0):

CNNs are generally designed for 2D (generally image) data. Hence, other usages are most likely a "hack" to CNN logic.

You can check how to extract features and classify texts with CNN through [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/).